Python: How to check if a URL is indeed a valid OpenID Connect server
If I have a URL, in Python, is there a way to check if it is a valid Open ID Connect server without actually connecting? For example, with QR URLs, I used pyotp.parse_uri
parse_uri(uri=value)

which raised a ValueError if value was not a valid QR URL. Is there something similar for Open ID Connects urls? Or do I have to attempt a connection to the URL to see if it is valid.
